# Не могу решить данную проблему IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Ругается на эту строку image = generate_doc(nameString[0], nameString[1], message.text)

```
import telebot
import config
import time


from telebot import types
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

token = config.TOKEN
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
dateGiven = False
users = {}

nameString = [];


def generate_doc(first_name, second_name, date):

    img = Image.open('Perevod.png') # Грузим Картинку

    nameFont = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',22) # Загрузка шрифта и установка размера
    pechatFont = ImageFont.truetype('CoreSansG.ttf',30) # Загрузка шрифта и установка размера
    dateFont = ImageFont.truetype('CoreSansG.ttf',73)
    namefont_color = '#414141' # Цвет шрифта
    datefont_color = '#ffffff' # Цвет шрифта
    

    name = first_name + ' ' + second_name # Соединяем имя и фамилию

    name_pos = (23,453) # Координаты имени и фамилии

    drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(img) # Создаем пикчу
    drawing.text(name_pos,name,font=nameFont,fill=namefont_color) # Пишем текст
    
    date_pos = (20,236) # Координаты даты
    drawing.text(date_pos,date + " Т",font=dateFont,fill=datefont_color) # Пишем дату
    
    
    textWidth = drawing.textsize(name,font=nameFont)
    pechat_pos = (25 + textWidth[0] + 50,256) # Координаты 
    drawing.text(pechat_pos,'',font=dateFont,fill=datefont_color) # Пишем дату
    
    dateGiven = False
    return img
    
    

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите имя и фамилию c большой буквы.')
    # при нажатии на кнопку Старт юзер запишется в переменную users
    users.setdefault(message.from_user.id, {})


@bot.message_handler()
def repeat_all_message(message: types.Message):
    if users.get("data_given") is not True:
        # не обязательно в split давать " " так как это знаечние по-умолчанию
        name_surname = message.text.split()

        if len(name_surname) == 2:  # проверка на длину списка (должно быть два слова от юзера отделенных пробелом)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите дату.')
            users['data_given'] = True
            users['words'] = name_surname
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ошибка! Введите имя и фамилию через пробел (с большой буквы).')
    else:
        image = generate_doc(nameString[0], nameString[1], message.text)  # дергаем нашу функцию
        image.save(str(message.from_user.id) + ' completedCert.jpg')  # сохраняем пикчу
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,
        hoto=open(str(message.from_user.id) + ' completedCert.jpg', 'rb'))  # отправляем пикчу
        users['data_given'] = False

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: просто поразительно, как вы написали такой сложный код, но не видите, что у вас в `nameString` ничего нет

Comment: Мне помогали в коде,теперь помочь некому ... если вам не сложно можете помочь ?! Не могу запустить бота

Comment: С таким уровнем вопросов вам вряд ли бесплатно помогать будут. Вам или на или на фриланс с этой задачей или взять учебник и научиться самому.